# How to unit test a filter that uses another filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I am using a filter within a filter. how should I go about with the unit test for this?

```
angular.module('filters')
.filter('scUrlHttp', function ($filter) {
    return function (url) {
        var result;
        var startingUrl = 'http://';
        var httpsStartingUrl = 'https://';

        if ($filter('startsWith')(url, startingUrl) || $filter('startsWith')(url, httpsStartingUrl)) {
            result = url;
        } else {
            result = startingUrl + url;
        }

        return result;
    };
});
```

Comment: get angular mocks or crate you own dummy filter versions. http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/05/27/ngmock-fundamentals-angularjs-testing-inject/

Comment: @Miguel how do I go about if I want to make my own dummy filter versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters are [just services with `Filter` suffix](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.6.6/src/ng/filter.js#L137).

A filter can be stubbed with:

```
var filterStub;
beforeEach(() => {
  filterStub = jasmine.createSpy();
  module('app', ($filterProvider) => {
    $filterProvider.register('startsWith', () => filterStub);
  });
});
```

Or:

```
var filterStub;
beforeEach(() => {
  filterStub = jasmine.createSpy();
  module('app', { startsWithFilter: filterStub });
});
```

And another filter can be tested with:

```
var anotherFilter = $filter('scUrlHttp');

filterStub.and.returnValue(true);
expect(anotherFilter(...)).toBe(...);
expect(filterStub).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...);
```